# New Chrome update blocks Java; how can I wait until permission is granted before calling my applet's code?

Tags: java, javascript, plugins, google-chrome, applet

Recently, Chrome got [a new update](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1247383) which blocks all plug-ins automatically.  It makes a bar appear asking the user for permission to enable it.  [This is what the bar looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMzv9.jpg)

My site has a button that when clicked, loads a Java applet and calls a method inside it.  The problem is that it tries to call the method immediately after the applet is loaded, before permission can be granted.  Naturally, this gives me an error in my Javascript saying that there is no such method.

How can I tell my button to wait until the applet has been granted permission before calling its methods?  I can't preload the applet because it's self-signed and I don't want the security dialog box to pop up until it's needed.  Normally that dialog box pauses the Javascript and resumes it when access has been granted or denied, but this new Chrome dialog runs in parallel to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your Applet call a Javascript method once it has successfully loaded. Your Javascript would then wait for this method to be called before attempting to access the Applet.

For Java-to-Javascript communication you have a couple of options. You could search Google for the `JSObject` class, although my understanding is that this requires browser-specific binaries and so may not be a workable solution. What is easier is just using the `AppletContext`'s `showDocument` method to execute Javascript, as described at http://www.brilliantsheep.com/java-to-javascript-communication-made-simple/.

In your Applet's init() method, for example, you would have code like the following:

```
getAppletContext().showDocument( "javascript:onAppletIsReady()", "_self" );
```

And then just define a method called onAppletIsReady in your javascript that executes whatever logic you were previously running as soon as the Applet was loaded.

Comment: Nice!  I tried this and it works beautifully.  However, I have one more issue: I can't detect if the user chooses to block the plugin.  The applet never gets to initialize so I can't call anything from it.  I'd like my page to fail gracefully, with an error message and suggestion, instead of hanging indefinitely.  Do you think there's a solution for that?

Comment: @terence I am not sure of a solution for that problem, although I have an idea. Web browsers are supposed to include the content inside the applet tags if the browser does not support applets, or they have been disabled. I am not sure if this includes the case you are describing, but you could try something like <applet ...><script type="text/javascript">onJavaDisabled();</script></applet> to execute some JS if the user declines Java. (Or just put the content here with a suggestion.) If you found my answer useful, accepting it is also much appreciated. Best of luck with your application!

Comment: Good idea, although Chrome seems to be just blocking it outright, and declining Java just makes the dialog box go away, without changing the state of anything.  Because of this, I don't think there's any solution.  I think I'll just set a timer and if there is no response, I'll remind the user to refresh the page and accept the plugin.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did your timer idea work?  Could you post the code you ended up with pls?